# Aws Ec2 no space left on device on initial launch and I have lost pem key file so not able to ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am stuck in a weird situation as **I have lost aws pem key** and device space is full.
I have created an AMI for that instance and launched a new instance. But not able to ssh. I checked system log from AWS console panel I can see many logs saying **No space left on device**.

I need to retrieve my database somehow. I have tried following things:

1. Created a AMI and launch new instance with more ram and more disk space , but still system logs print no  space left on device on instance launch.
2. Tried to connect with Session manager but instance is not listed in target Instance section.
   I have attached same AMI role with new fresh instance , SSM login is working fine for this.
3. I tried to clear tmp files using user-data script. but user-data script is not working on this instance. I have already tested this script on other instance so no error in script.

**System logs are as follows:**

````
Welcome to [1mUbuntu 18.04.2 LTS[0m!

[   10.531691] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ip-172-31-24-157>.
[   12.830939] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   12.846800] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Swap.
[   12.856515] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Set up automount Arbitrary Executabâ€¦rmats File System Automount Point.
[   12.892246] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   12.908337] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice System Slice.
[   12.922846] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Journal Socket.
         Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
         Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
         Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
         Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on udev Control Socket.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
         Mounting Huge Pages File System...
         Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Syslog Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Huge Pages File System.
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create list of required staâ€¦vice nodes for the current kernel.
         Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Journal Service.
         Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[   13.270699] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[   13.286282] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
[   13.299728] systemd-journald[411]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   13.318858] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
[   13.345217] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
[   13.355887] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
[[0;32m  OK  [[   13.369018] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
0m] Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
[   13.381230] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set the console keyboard layout.
[   13.405754] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
[   13.483989] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
[   13.502726] systemd-journald[411]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors,â€¦sing dmeventd or progress polling.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting AppArmor initialization...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting ebtables ruleset management...
         Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 10583...
[   13.951256] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
         Mounting Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 2996...
         Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 10823...
         Mounting Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 2333...
         Mounting Mount unit for core18, revision 1988...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load Kernel Modules.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console font and keymap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 10583.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 2333.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 1944.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
         Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
         Mounting FUSE Control File System...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ebtables ruleset management.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 10823.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device /dev/ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started AppArmor initialization.
         Starting Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd.
[   18.975182] cloud-init[418]: Cloud-init v. 18.4-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'init-local' at Fri, 23 Jul 2021 13:15:16 +0000. Up 18.94 seconds.
[   18.987048] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,167 - util.py[DEBUG]: Cloud-init v. 18.4-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'init-local' at Fri, 23 Jul 2021 13:15:16 +0000. Up 18.94 seconds.
[   19.000752] cloud-init[418]: tee: /var/log/cloud-init-output.log: No space left on device
[   19.007799] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,168 - main.py[DEBUG]: No kernel command line url found.
[   19.015190] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,168 - main.py[DEBUG]: Closing stdin.
[   19.023047] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,173 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/log/cloud-init.log - ab: [644] 0 bytes
[   19.031751] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,174 - util.py[DEBUG]: Changing the ownership of /var/log/cloud-init.log to 102:4
[   19.044449] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,174 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
[   19.065557] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,174 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/data/no-net
[   19.141068] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,196 - stages.py[DEBUG]: cache invalid in datasource: DataSourceEc2
[   19.153376] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,196 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local/check-cache: SUCCESS: cache invalid in datasource: DataSourceEc2
[   19.169136] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,196 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance
[   19.201608] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,197 - stages.py[DEBUG]: Using distro class <class 'cloudinit.distros.ubuntu.Distro'>
[   19.222225] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,198 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Looking for data source in: ['Ec2', 'None'], via packages ['', 'cloudinit.sources'] that matches dependencies ['FILESYSTEM']
[   19.242170] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,200 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Searching for local data source in: ['DataSourceEc2Local']
[   19.256006] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,200 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-local/search-Ec2Local: searching for local data from DataSourceEc2Local
[   19.274268] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,200 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Seeing if we can get any data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2Local'>
[   19.285129] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,201 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Update datasource metadata and network config due to events: New instance first boot
[   19.299070] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,201 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/hypervisor/uuid (quiet=False)
[   19.308650] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,201 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 37 bytes from /sys/hypervisor/uuid
[   19.318173] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,201 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['systemd-detect-virt', '--quiet', '--container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   19.336654] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,206 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['running-in-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   19.350025] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,208 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['lxc-is-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   19.369410] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,210 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/1/environ (quiet=False)
[   19.399949] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,210 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 173 bytes from /proc/1/environ
[   19.407182] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,210 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/self/status (quiet=False)
[   19.429612] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,210 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 1305 bytes from /proc/self/status
[   19.483364] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,211 - util.py[DEBUG]: dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial returned ec2a2020-1476-4e5d-c9c3-18599bf93d03
[   19.498724] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,211 - DataSourceEc2.py[DEBUG]: strict_mode: warn, cloud_platform=AWS
[   19.522059] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,215 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /etc/os-release (quiet=False)
[   19.535084] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,216 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 386 bytes from /etc/os-release
[   19.557309] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,216 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Found unstable nic names: ['eth0']; calling udevadm settle
[   19.574102] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,217 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   19.590374] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,229 - util.py[DEBUG]: Waiting for udev events to settle took 0.012 seconds
[   19.598833] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,230 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier (quiet=False)
[   19.606833] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,230 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/dormant (quiet=False)
[   19.615485] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,230 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate (quiet=False)
[   19.625035] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,230 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 5 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
[   19.635991] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,230 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/address (quiet=False)
[   19.644711] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,231 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/address
[   19.652647] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,237 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local/search-Ec2Local: FAIL: no local data found from DataSourceEc2Local
[   19.662459] cloud-init[418]: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,237 - util.py[WARNING]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2Local'> failed
[   19.705223] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,237 - util.py[DEBUG]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2Local'> failed
[   19.715934] cloud-init[418]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   19.721390] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/__init__.py", line 669, in find_source
[   19.729278] cloud-init[418]:     if s.update_metadata([EventType.BOOT_NEW_INSTANCE]):
[   19.736583] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/__init__.py", line 558, in update_metadata
[   19.750515] cloud-init[418]:     result = self.get_data()
[   19.756540] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/DataSourceEc2.py", line 383, in get_data
[   19.798954] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/DataSourceEc2.py", line 105, in _get_data
[   19.813026] cloud-init[418]:     with EphemeralDHCPv4(self.fallback_interface):
[   19.820638] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/net/dhcp.py", line 46, in __enter__
[   19.831975] cloud-init[418]:     leases = maybe_perform_dhcp_discovery(self.iface)
[   19.843333] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/net/dhcp.py", line 97, in maybe_perform_dhcp_discovery
[   19.854212] cloud-init[418]:     with temp_utils.tempdir(prefix='cloud-init-dhcp-', needs_exe=True) as tdir:
[   19.861016] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
[   19.867347] cloud-init[418]:     return next(self.gen)
[   19.871694] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/temp_utils.py", line 88, in tempdir
[   19.879741] cloud-init[418]:     tdir = mkdtemp(**kwargs)
[   19.884070] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/temp_utils.py", line 98, in mkdtemp
[   19.892514] cloud-init[418]:     return tempfile.mkdtemp(**kwargs)
[   19.899562] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 509, in mkdtemp
[   19.905313] cloud-init[418]:     _os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
[   19.911762] cloud-init[418]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-daswbl27'
[   19.920700] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,398 - main.py[DEBUG]: No local datasource found
[   19.926883] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,400 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/name_assign_type (quiet=False)
[   19.945952] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,400 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Found unstable nic names: ['eth0']; calling udevadm settle
[   19.956599] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,400 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   19.966103] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,437 - util.py[DEBUG]: Waiting for udev events to settle took 0.037 seconds
[   19.997987] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,438 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate (quiet=False)
[   20.007682] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,438 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 5 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
[   20.020081] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,438 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/address (quiet=False)
[   20.033673] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,439 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/address
[   20.047206] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,439 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/address (quiet=False)
[   20.055665] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,439 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/address
[   20.063182] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,439 - stages.py[DEBUG]: applying net config names for {'config': [{'type': 'physical', 'name': 'eth0', 'mac_address': '0a:29:64:0d:99:95', 'subnets': [{'type': 'dhcp'}]}], 'version': 1}
[   20.074857] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,439 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/device/device (quiet=False)
[   20.083923] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,439 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/addr_assign_type (quiet=False)
[   20.092249] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,440 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 2 bytes from /sys/class/net/lo/addr_assign_type
[   20.100710] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,440 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/uevent (quiet=False)
[   20.109966] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,440 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 23 bytes from /sys/class/net/lo/uevent
[   20.170402] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,440 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/uevent (quiet=False)
[   20.182418] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 25 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/uevent
[   20.191083] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/address (quiet=False)
[   20.199803] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/address
[   20.209175] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/device/device (quiet=False)
[   20.219284] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/operstate (quiet=False)
[   20.229438] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 8 bytes from /sys/class/net/lo/operstate
[   20.238694] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate (quiet=False)
[   20.246937] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,441 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 5 bytes from /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
[   20.254889] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,442 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['ip', '-6', 'addr', 'show', 'permanent', 'scope', 'global'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   20.265483] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,543 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['ip', '-4', 'addr', 'show'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   20.284284] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,549 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: no work necessary for renaming of [['0a:29:64:0d:99:95', 'eth0', 'vif', None]]
[   20.295737] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,550 - stages.py[INFO]: Applying network configuration from fallback bringup=False: {'config': [{'type': 'physical', 'name': 'eth0', 'mac_address': '0a:29:64:0d:99:95', 'subnets': [{'type': 'dhcp'}]}], 'version': 1}
[   20.323658] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,562 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Selected renderer 'netplan' from priority list: None
[   20.342387] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,580 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml - wb: [644] 473 bytes
[   20.357831] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,593 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['netplan', 'generate'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   20.403061] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,784 - main.py[DEBUG]: [local] Exiting without datasource
[   20.413703] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,785 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/uptime (quiet=False)
[   20.425002] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,785 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 12 bytes from /proc/uptime
[   20.436912] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,786 - util.py[DEBUG]: cloud-init mode 'init' took 0.658 seconds (0.66)
[   20.444217] cloud-init[418]: FALLBACK: 2021-07-23 13:15:16,786 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local: FAIL: searching for local datasources
[   20.453834] cloud-init[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).
See 'systemctl status cloud-init-local.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network (Pre).
         Starting Network Service...
[418]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   20.485193] cloud-init[418]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   20.494029] cloud-init[418]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   20.505563] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[   20.515087] cloud-init[418]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.4', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   20.524489] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 904, in main
[   20.532712] cloud-init[418]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   20.538776] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2514, in log_time
[   20.545886] cloud-init[418]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   20.550702] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 676, in status_wrapper
[   20.589274] cloud-init[418]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[   20.596284] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[   20.609015] cloud-init[418]:     raise e[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Service.
         Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Name Resolution.

[   20.638185] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file
[   20.655224] [[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Name Resolution.cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 650, in close
[   20.729144] cloud-init[418]:     self._closer.close()
[   20.735725] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 584, in close
[   20.743558] cloud-init[418]:     self.file.close()
[   20.748216] cloud-init[418]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   20.754573] cloud-init[418]: Error in sys.excepthook:
[   20.762944] cloud-init[418]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   20.769538] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 155, in apport_excepthook
[   20.780082] cloud-init[418]:     pr.write(f)
[   20.784215] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 402, in write
[   20.793480] cloud-init[418]:     file.write(v.replace(b'\n', b'\n '))
[   20.800697] cloud-init[418]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   20.828801] cloud-init[418]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   20.846528] cloud-init[418]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   20.852754] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 155, in apport_excepthook
[   20.861908] cloud-init[418]:     pr.write(f)
[   20.875028] cloud-init[418]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   20.885817] cloud-init[418]: Original exception was:
[   20.892553] cloud-init[418]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   20.898314] cloud-init[418]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   20.905175] cloud-init[418]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   20.909974] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[   20.915669] cloud-init[418]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.4', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   20.923754] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 904, in main
[   20.942039] cloud-init[418]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   20.952158] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2514, in log_time
[   20.961154] cloud-init[418]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   20.967652] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 676, in status_wrapper
[   20.975579] cloud-init[418]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[   20.986689] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
[   20.994419] cloud-init[418]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[   21.009619] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[   21.020025] cloud-init[418]:     raise e
[   21.025220] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file
[   21.037092] cloud-init[418]:     tf.close()
[   21.041402] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 650, in close
[   21.048127] cloud-init[418]:     self._closer.close()
[   21.053340] cloud-init[418]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 584, in close
[   21.064496] cloud-init[418]:     self.file.close()
[   21.070017] cloud-init[418]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...
[   22.969848] cloud-init[691]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   22.975883] cloud-init[691]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   22.982844] cloud-init[691]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   22.988027] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[   22.994186] cloud-init[691]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.4', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   23.001627] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 904, in main
[   23.011057] cloud-init[691]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   23.018593] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2514, in log_time
[   23.031458] cloud-init[691]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   23.037645] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 653, in status_wrapper
[   23.046250] cloud-init[691]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[   23.052210] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
[   23.060274] cloud-init[691]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[   23.064442] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[   23.072496] cloud-init[691]:     raise e
[   23.075988] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file[   23.147598] cloud-init[691]:     file.write(v.replace(b'\n', b'\n '))
[   23.151878] cloud-init[691]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   23.156413] cloud-init[691]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   23.164339] cloud-init[691]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   23.167806] cloud-init[691]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 155, in apport_excepthook
[   23.17759 ```
````

Comment: Advice on [expanding the root EBS volume](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that log i expect the system will be pretty broken if it completes booting at all. That might limit your options. I can think of 2 options to try:

1. When you restore from an AMI you can specify a different key(ie create a new keypair) - did you try that? This might not work if the disk is completely full - not sure. This is potentially an easy fix though so worth trying.
2. More drastic option is to clone your broken instances disk (ie: restore the AMI's snapshot as a new ebs volume & increase its size). Then create a new temp ec2 instance, and attach the EBS volume copy as a 2nd drive. Boot and login to the temp VM so you can delete files / adjust disks and partitions, or just extract your data/config files.

Comment: Thanks dear, I opted for option 2 and recovered all the data.